# Is making changes to Jquery Validation to get custom style a bad practice?

Tags: jquery, html, css

I need to add a icon after a input field when required field is not fill up, me and a friend came up with a different approach.

My approach is to modify the highlight function in Jquery.Validation, add a class to the parent element of the input, which is a div so i can style it with pseudo element.

My friend approach is to add a div after the input so we can style it. He did mention we shouldn't use a HTML element just for styling.

But he also said making changes to a library is a real bad practice.
So my question is which approach is better?

Comment: If you mean that you're editing the source of the plugin itself, then yes it's bad practice because it means you cannot easily upgrade the plugin in the future. The validate plugin offers you plenty of event-based methods which you can use to amend the DOM when required. Using a HTML element just for styling is absolutely fine - it's what they are for.

Comment: If you change a library and a new version of this library get's released, you have to make the changes again. If the updates come quite often, you'll make the same changes also very often. So I would advise against changing any external library unless you really have to.

Comment: i notice that the code i change is wrap with $.extend($.validator, {...
Is there any way i can extend this in a proper way? It's the Highlight and unhighlight function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Making changes to a library is **definitely a bad practice**.

What about these two approaches - they are both good. jQuery validation plugin wouldn't provide so many options to override behaviour, if it were a bad practice.  That's how it is supposed to work.

You can easily provide any CSS styling options simply by describing `valid` and `error` classes in your CSS:

```
form.error { 
    color: red;
    border: 1px solid red; // yes, it is disgusting. just for an example
}

form.valid {
    color: green;
}
```

If you want to add more logics like adding an element, moving it etc., you can simply describe it in `errorPlacement`, `highlight` and `unhighlight` functions:

```
$("form").validate({
    rules: {},
    messages: {},
    highlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).addClass(errorClass); // default highlight action
        // any custom actions with element or element.form
    }, 
    unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
        $(element).removeClass(errorClass); // default unhighlight action
        // any custom actions with element or element.form
    }, 
    errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
        var alert = $("<div/>").addClass("alert alert-danger").insertAfter(element); // Show error in a Bootstrap alert, for example
        alert.append(error);
    }
});
```

According to [documentation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/validate):

`errorPlacement` customizes placement of created error labels.
`highlight` customizes how invalid fields are highlighted.
`unhighlight` customizes how `highlight` actions are reverted.

Comment: @Cheelam1220 Right in the place where you call your `.validate()` method. You describe these functions as a part of `options`, which you pass to this function. Refer to documentation - link is available in the answer.